# T-SQL query to remove non matching value from ColumnA where value doesn't exist in ColumnB

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have two databases, with the following tables:

**DatabaseA**
TableA
ColumnA (varChar(10)

**DatabaseB**
TableB
ColumnB (varChar(10)

I need a query that:

- Ignores NULLs or empty strings
- Finds rows where the value of ColumnA does not exist in columnB

  - In this case, replaces the value of the non matching row in ColumnA with '' (empty string)

This is in a MS SQL Server 2008 environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` as shown below:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET columnA = ''
FROM
    TableA 
    LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.columnA = TableB.columnB
WHERE
    TableA.columnA IS NOT NULL AND TableA.columnA <> '' AND
    TableB.columnB IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE TableA 
SET ColumnA = ''
WHERE  ColumnA IS NOT NULL 
  AND ColumnA <> '' 
  AND NOT EXISTS
     (
     SELECT *
     FROM TableB WHERE TableB.ColumnB = TableA.ColumnA
     )
```